# asp.net Multiple Control with same ID issue in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, updatepanel

I'm doing following code below as

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upContent">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <cube:PlaceHolder ID="phContent" runat="server">
            </cube:PlaceHolder>
                <uc1:ProgressNote runat="server" ID="ProgressNote" />                                    
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now problem is that when I call findcontrol for ProgressNote in page Its not find because ProgressNote is outside panel, as findcontrol override method find that control in "phContent" panel. for this I put ProgressNote control inside panel like below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upContent">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <cube:PlaceHolder ID="phContent" runat="server">
                    <uc1:ProgressNote runat="server" ID="ProgressNote" />                                    
                </cube:PlaceHolder>
            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

now this time I have exception "Multiple controls with the same ID 'ProgressNote' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs", But there is not same ID in the code. Where I'm doing wrong please help me out in this. Thanks in advance
This is how I'm finding control:

```
 protected void onControlEvent(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, EventInfo> parent in this.RegisteredEvents[e.ControlID])
        {
            if (parent.Key != this.ClientID)
            {
                IBaseControl ctrl = (IBaseControl)this.PlaceHolder.FindControl(parent.Key);
                if (parent.Value.EventName == e.EventName)
                {
                    ctrl.ControlEvent(sender, new EventInfoEventArgs() { EventInfo = parent.Value, e = e.EventArgs });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ctrl will be null

Comment: How many ProgressNote are you binding on the page?

Comment: One time! I just drag drop control as above @Dev

Comment: Can you paste some code how do you finding ProgressNote?

Comment: @Dev yeh sure please check above